# $E/F$ is an extension with radicals of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, radicals, kummer-theory

We have that $E/F$ is an extension Kummer of degree $n$ and that $F$ contains a $n$-th unit root $\omega$ with $\text{ord} (\omega)=n$.

I want to show that $E/F$ is an extension with radicals of order $n$.

$$$$

I have found the following theorem:

[image]

Could we maybe use that theorem in this case? So, do we have to show that the Galois group of the extension has an exponent dividing $n$ ?

Comment: Could you define precisely what you call a "Kummer extension" ?

Comment: A Kummer extension is a finite Galois extension from which the Galois group is abelian. @nguyenquangdo

Comment: No. A finite Galois extension E/F whose Galois group G is abelian is just called ... abelian. Classifying abelian extensions is not an easy matter. This is known for number fields, in the VERY deep theory called "class field" theory. Coming back to your problem, you must suppose that F contains a primitive n-th root of 1, n is prime to the characteristic of F and G is abelian with exponent n dividing n. Then the theorem you cite holds true, and your E/F is called a Kummer extension. But then the answer to your question is a tautology.

Comment: Do we have that  n is prime to the characteristic of F because ord(ω)=n? And how do we know that the exponent of G is n? Then I thought to use the direction "$\Rightarrow$" of the theorem, i.e., that knowing that E/F is a Kummer extension and that G has an exponent dividing n, it follows that $E=F(\sqrt[n]{a_1}, \ldots , \sqrt[n]{a_r})$. @nguyenquangdo

Comment: Is this way wrong? @nguyenquangdo

Comment: 1) You must add the condition on the exponent of G, because Kummer's theory simply does not work if there are not enough roots of 1 in F   2) The restriction on char(F) is needed to ensure separability when adding n-th roots of elements

Comment: Ahh... To show that $E/F$ is an extension with radicals of order $n$ we have to show that there exists a chain $F=F_0\leq F_1\leq \ldots \leq F_r=E$ and $a_i\in F_i$, $i=1, \ldots , r$ such that $F_i=F_{i-1}(a_i)$ and $a_i^n\in F_{i-1}$, right? @nguyenquangdo

Comment: Yes, and this is given by Kummer's theorem which you cited, provided the correct hypotheses of course. But perhaps we should go to "chat", as suggested by the moderator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50341/discussion-between-mary-star-and-nguyen-quang-do).